# Programa de Reproducción de vídeos java

Tags: java, vlcj

Llevo unos días intentando hacer un programa para reproducir vídeos en formato mp4, jpg, avi......

Utilizando la librería `vlci` he visto que utiliza las dll del VLC y es la más aconsejada que yo separa para reproducir estos formatos. He visto en Google ejemplos y he copiado estos ejemplos a mi PC con el [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) y [netbeans-8.1](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.1) pero en ninguno de los dos casos me funcionan, no reproduce nada y me salta un error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'libvlc': No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
>
> ```
> at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
> at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
> at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:142)
> at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
> at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
> at Reproductor.<clinit>(Reproductor.java:30)
> ```

Supuestamente esto dice que no encuentra la `libvlc.dll` y mi ruta en el programa y la dll se encuentran ahí donde está marcado. No entiendo por qué marca este error...
Después de buscar en Google información sobre el error he querido dejar este post a ver si alguien a dado con el mismo error y como solucionarlo.

No sé si el que tenga un sistema operativo Windows 8.1 64 bits influye en esto. Quizás está librería solo fluya para sistemas 32 bits, no lo sé...
Si alguien necesita ver el código del programa que lo pida...

Programa:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;


public class Reproductor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent player;
    private File file;
    static{
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/VLC/");

        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    }
    //bandera para controlar la reproduccion de video y el cambio en el avance de video
    private boolean band = true;

    /**
     * Creates new form Reproductor
     */
    public Reproductor() {
        initComponents();

        setTitle("VLCJ Player");//nombre de reproductor
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centrar en pantalla
        player = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        //se añade reproductor 
        jPanel2.add(player);        
        player.setSize(jPanel2.getSize());                
        player.setVisible(true);                
        //slider control de volumen
        sldVolumen.setMinimum(0);
        sldVolumen.setMaximum(100);
        //slider control progreso
        sldProgress.setMinimum(0);
        sldProgress.setMaximum(100);
        sldProgress.setValue(0);
        sldProgress.setEnabled(false);

        //Control abrir archivo        
        btnOpenFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Videos", "mp4","flv","webm","3gp","dat");
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                //fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\videos\\tmp\\"));
                if ( fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){            
                    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();                                     
                    btnPlay.doClick();
                }
            }            
        });

        //Control captura de ventana
        btnSnapshot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(file!=null){
                    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();        
                    String newPath = absolutePath .substring(0, absolutePath .length()-4) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";                
                    if( player.getMediaPlayer().saveSnapshot(new File(newPath)) )               
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Snapshot: " + newPath );  
                }
            }            
        });

        //Control de reproduccion
        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (file!=null){                    
                    player.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(file.getAbsolutePath());    
                    sldVolumen.setValue(  player.getMediaPlayer().getVolume() );
                    sldProgress.setEnabled(true);
                    setTitle( file.getName() + " - VLCJ Player");    
                }
            }
        }); 

        //Control de pausa
        btnPause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               player.getMediaPlayer().setPause( player.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()?true:false );                                   
            }
        }); 

        //Control detener reproduccion
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              player.getMediaPlayer().stop();   
              sldProgress.setValue(0);
              sldProgress.setEnabled(false);
              setTitle("VLCJ Player");
            }
        }); 

       //Control silenciar 
       btnMute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton) actionEvent.getSource();                
                player.getMediaPlayer().mute( abstractButton.getModel().isSelected() );                
            }
        });

        //Control slider cambiar volumen
        sldVolumen.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Object source = e.getSource();                                
                player.getMediaPlayer().setVolume( ((JSlider) source).getValue() );
            }            
        });

        //Listener de reproductor para mostrar el progreso en la reproduccion del video 
        player.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mp, float pos)
            {
                if(band){
                    int value = Math.min(100, Math.round(pos * 100.0f));            
                    sldProgress.setValue(value);                                                    
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){

            }

        });

        //Listener para el slider progress
        sldProgress.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                band= false;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                band = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

        });

        //Control para cambiar a posicion de reproduccion
        sldProgress.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public synchronized void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if( !band ){
                    Object source = e.getSource();                                
                    float np = ((JSlider) source).getValue() / 100f;                    
                    player.getMediaPlayer().setPosition(np);    
                }

            }            
        });

    }//end: constructor



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        sldProgress = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        btnPlay = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPause = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnStop = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnMute = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        sldVolumen = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jToolBar1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar();
        btnOpenFile = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator();
        btnSnapshot = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jPanel3.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel3, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        jPanel3.add(sldProgress);

        jPanel1.add(jPanel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

        jPanel4.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        btnPlay.setText("Play");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        jPanel4.add(btnPlay, gridBagConstraints);

        btnPause.setText("Pause");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        jPanel4.add(btnPause, gridBagConstraints);

        btnStop.setText("Stop");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        jPanel4.add(btnStop, gridBagConstraints);

        btnMute.setText("Mute");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        jPanel4.add(btnMute, gridBagConstraints);

        sldVolumen.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 23));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        jPanel4.add(sldVolumen, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel1.add(jPanel4, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jPanel2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 100));
        jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
        jPanel2.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel2, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jToolBar1.setFloatable(false);
        jToolBar1.setRollover(true);

        btnOpenFile.setText("Open File");
        btnOpenFile.setFocusable(false);
        btnOpenFile.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnOpenFile.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jToolBar1.add(btnOpenFile);
        jToolBar1.add(jSeparator1);

        btnSnapshot.setText("Snapshot");
        btnSnapshot.setFocusable(false);
        btnSnapshot.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnSnapshot.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jToolBar1.add(btnSnapshot);

        getContentPane().add(jToolBar1, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reproductor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reproductor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reproductor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Reproductor.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Reproductor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton btnMute;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnOpenFile;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPause;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPlay;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSnapshot;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStop;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JToolBar.Separator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JToolBar jToolBar1;
    private javax.swing.JSlider sldProgress;
    private javax.swing.JSlider sldVolumen;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: Estado indagando sobre el tema y efectivamente el problema recae sobre mi sistema operativo 64 bits no es compatible con el Vlcj Java framework for the vlc media player... Enlace la libreria.... http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/ A ver si con paciencia encuentro una solucion a mi problema jajajaja

Comment: Aquí encontré otra alternativa, si que es cierto que se recomienda VLCj pero puede que esta te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978075/library-that-can-extract-and-play-video-file

Comment: hola yo tuve el mismo problema pero debes descargar la libreria para 64 bits desde videolan, luego de eso deberia funcionarte correctamente, saludos

Comment: Muchos de estos problemas se originan al usar un IDE, muchas veces los IDEs ponen una carpeta con los .class en otra ubicación y no copian los recursos que necesitamos en una ruta relativa a esa carpeta, si pudieras darnos más información tal vez te podríamso ayudar mejor.

Comment: Guiate con esta explicación. https://www.javatpoint.com/javafx-playing-video

Comment: Por qué no usas [tag:jmf] ?

Comment: además creo que la librería se llama [tag:vlcj] no vlci

Answer (score 1):

Puede que sea algo tarde, pero al ver que nadie responde y porque una solución puede que este relacionada con la versión de `VLC` que tengas, si tu sistema operativo es de **64 bits**, la versión de `VLC` debe ser igual de **64 bits**. Si no al momento de querer usar:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/");
```

No se podrá cargar la librería.